# Flutter Sqflite syntax error in CREATE TABLE

Tags: sql, flutter, sqlite, dart, sqflite

I created a database with sqflite in Flutter. When I try to insert data I get the error

```
error DatabaseException(near ")": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE nutritionTable(
_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
calories INTEGER NOT NULL,
carbs INTEGER NOT NULL,
fat INTEGER NOT NULL,
protein INTEGER NOT NULL,
))
```

My code to create a table looks like this:

```
  static final _dbName = 'userNutritionSql.db';
  static final _dbVersion = 1;
  static final _tableName = 'nutritionTable';

  static final columnId = '_id';
  static final columnCalories = 'calories';
  static final columnCarbs = 'carbs';
  static final columnFat = 'fat';
  static final columnProtein = 'protein';

Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async{
    final idType = 'INTEGER PRIMARY KEY';
    final intType = 'INTEGER NOT NULL';

    await db.execute(
      '''
      CREATE TABLE $_tableName(
      $columnId $idType,
      $columnCalories $intType,
      $columnCarbs $intType,
      $columnFat $intType,
      $columnProtein $intType,
      )
      '''
    );
  }
```

I cant spot the syntax error, does anyone has an idea whats wrong?

Comment: On the last row you don't need a `,`. Simply close the bracket.

Comment: Remove the `,` from `$columnProtein $intType,`

Comment: Thank you guys! Didnt thought this would be a problem :D